# Creating a Dropdown Menu with CSS Not Working

Tags: html, css

The dropdown menu (sub) does not appear right below the element it is supposed to when I hover on the navbar. How can I get it to appear below it instead of to the right of it? Also, how can I get the extra spacing on the left side of each menu to disappear? I tried setting the padding to 0, but that did not change anything.

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    font-size: 93%;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 0;

}

.navbar > li{
    display:inline-block;
    
}

.navbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: none;
}

.navbar a {
    float: center;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    
}

.navbar li:hover ul.sub {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}


ul.sub {
    padding-left: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

ul.sub a {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
 <ul class = "navbar">
    <!--add dropdown menu links for everything except collaboration-->
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="project.html">About FRES(H)</a>  
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "safety.html">Safety</a></li>
            <li><a href = "sense.html">Sense</a></li>
            <li><a href = "express.html">Express</a></li>
            <li><a href = "fresh.html">Keep Fresh</a></li>
            <li><a href = "notebook.html">Notebook</a></li>
            <li><a href = "interlab.html">Interlab</a></li>
            <li><a href = "protocols.html">Protocols</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="modelling.html">Models</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "etnr1.html">Protein Modelling Etnr1</a></li>
            <li><a href = "etnr2.html">Protein Modelling Etnr2</a></li>
            <li><a href = "internal.html">Internal Cellular Model</a></li>
            <li><a href = "diffusion.html">Macroscopic Diffusion Model</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="software.html">Technology</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "primer.html">Primer Design App</a></li>
            <li><a href = "smartphone.html">SmartPhone App</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="humanpractices.html">Human-Centered Design</a> 
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "human.html">Integrated Human Practices</a></li>
            <li><a href = "outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
            <li><a href = "knowledgetheory.html">Theory of Knowledge</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    <li><a href ="http://2016.igem.org/Team:Sydney_Australia/Collaboration">Engagement</a></li> 
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="team.html">Meet the Team</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "attributions.html">Attributions</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li> 
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="achievements.html">Awards</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "parts.html">Parts</a></li>
            <li><a href = "medals.html">Medals</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! You just added the :hover to the wrong div.

Make the following changes:
`display:none` to `ul.sub` and `.navbar li:hover ul.sub` instead of `.navbar:hover ul.sub`

UPDATE: to centre the `ul.sub`, use `display: block`. To remove padding, assign value of 0, instead of 'none'. See example below:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    font-size: 93%;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left: 0;

}

.navbar > li{
    display:inline-block;
    
}

.navbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: none;
}

.navbar a {
    float: center;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    
}

.navbar li:hover ul.sub {
display: block;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}


ul.sub {
    padding-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
}

ul.sub a {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
 <ul class = "navbar">
    <!--add dropdown menu links for everything except collaboration-->
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="project.html">About FRES(H)</a>  
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "safety.html">Safety</a></li>
            <li><a href = "sense.html">Sense</a></li>
            <li><a href = "express.html">Express</a></li>
            <li><a href = "fresh.html">Keep Fresh</a></li>
            <li><a href = "notebook.html">Notebook</a></li>
            <li><a href = "interlab.html">Interlab</a></li>
            <li><a href = "protocols.html">Protocols</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="modelling.html">Models</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "etnr1.html">Protein Modelling Etnr1</a></li>
            <li><a href = "etnr2.html">Protein Modelling Etnr2</a></li>
            <li><a href = "internal.html">Internal Cellular Model</a></li>
            <li><a href = "diffusion.html">Macroscopic Diffusion Model</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="software.html">Technology</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "primer.html">Primer Design App</a></li>
            <li><a href = "smartphone.html">SmartPhone App</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="humanpractices.html">Human-Centered Design</a> 
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "human.html">Integrated Human Practices</a></li>
            <li><a href = "outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
            <li><a href = "knowledgetheory.html">Theory of Knowledge</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    <li><a href ="http://2016.igem.org/Team:Sydney_Australia/Collaboration">Engagement</a></li> 
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="team.html">Meet the Team</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "attributions.html">Attributions</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li> 
    <li class = "dropdown">
        <li><a href ="achievements.html">Awards</a>
        <ul class = "sub">
            <li><a href = "parts.html">Parts</a></li>
            <li><a href = "medals.html">Medals</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was able to get that to work, thanks, but I can't figure out how to center the menu below the part of the navbar that I'm hovering on, and how to get rid of the extra space at the sides of the menus. Would you be able to give me any advice on this?

Comment: Just added some more details, check it out ^^^^ :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!